# How to determine if WP_DEBUG is enabled?

Tags: php, theme-development

I believe I saw this done in a few plugins before, but it has been awhile and I have no clue what plugins offered this or how they offered it, but what I am trying to achieve is this...

I want offer a developer mode for my custom theme I'm creating.

I am running a function that if enabled will load the prettified files instead of the minified files for developers. But, I also want to load the prettified files if WP_DEBUG is enabled.

Is there a way I can check if a user has WP_DEBUG enabled?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just check the value of the constant.

```
if( WP_DEBUG === true ) { 
    // enabled 
} else {
    // not enabled 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still new to php and didn't know I could do that, and didn't know the lingo to turn up a search results based on that lingo. But, now I do so that will help in the future as well. I can confirm this works, thanks! This is beautiful :)

Comment: No worries :) we were all new at one point or another!

Comment: Yeah and thanks again. I tweaked the answer to include what I needed as I  wasn't specific about that part. I added the check for my developer mode function and checking the value of the WP_DEBUG constant.

Comment: No worries, I didn't accept the edit as it wasn't really pertinent to the actual question. It didn't help clarify anything, it might potentially confuse a simple answer.

Comment: we also make sure `WP_DEBUG` is defined & then it is set to true.
`if ( defined('WP_DEBUG') && true === WP_DEBUG) {
   // do something
}`